# Capybara::Poltergeist::TimeoutError

Tags: ruby, linux, capybara, poltergeist

Everitime i try to take a screenshot from my instance, from the website i'm help developing it always gives me the same mistake:

> Timed out waiting for response to {"name":"visit","args":["localhost:3000/login"]}.
>   It's possible that this happened because something took a very long time (for example a page load was slow). If so, setting the Poltergeist :timeout option to a higher value will help (see the docs for details). If increasing the timeout does not help, this is probably a bug in Poltergeist - please report it to the issue tracker.

With some tests, i detected that we can't take a screenshot if the server its on the same machine.

I pass to explain. I try to take a screenshot from my machine (that is the server, its on development ) and it gives me the timeout. But if a try to take a screenshot from the same page, but its running on my associate machine, it works. I just don't now how to resolve this.

Can someone help me please?
I'm using Poltergeist, Capybara and PhantomJS.

Comment: @Uri no doubt OP is calling poltergeist's `page.save_screenshot`.

Comment: Does `save_and_open_page` work?